# how to filter story by it's belonging tag

Tags: python, django

I have two models news and category, and in news I have foreignkey of category. I know how to display news with same category in a single template. but furthermore, in my home page I'm trying to display featured news of each category. this is where I'm having problem.
this is my models.py

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey("Tag")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    top = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    featuredInCat = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = StoryManager()



class NewsQueryset(models.query.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(active=True)
    def featuredInCat(self):
        return self.filter(featuredInCat=True)


class NewsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return NewsQueryset(self.model, using=self._db)
    def get_featuredInCat(self):
        return self.get_queryset().active().featuredInCat()
    def all(self):
        return self.get_queryset().active()


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True)
```

In views.py

```
def category_list(request):
    categoryList = NewsCategory.objects.all()

    featuredInCat = News.objects.get_featuredInCat()
    context = {
        "featuredInCat":featuredInCat
        "categoryList":categoryList,


}
    return render(request,"news/category_list.html", context)
```

In my template

```
  {% for category in categoryList %}
<div class='col-sm-4'>
<div id="container">{{category.title}}</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for x in featuredInCat %}
 <a href='{{ x.get_absolute_url }}'><li class="unique">{{x.title}}</li></a>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </div>  

<hr>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

then this shows the featuredInCat in every category where featuredInCat should be shown only in its Category section.
how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your for loop to iterate over the correct objects

```
{% for x in category.news_set.get_featuredInCat %}
```

You won't need the context variable anymore

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [the built-in `regroup` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) of django. You will need to change your template to something like this:

```
{% regroup featuredInCat by category as news_list %}

<ul>
{% for news in news_list %}
    <li>{{ news.grouper.title }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in news.list %}
          <li>{{ item.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```